# ODE and BVP: NDSolve errors

Tags: differential-equations

The mathematical problem is shown [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24592/ode-with-boundary-value-problem-does-not-work). I tried to solve writing the

```
A0 = 2.0377638272727268`;
A1 = -7.105521894545453`;
A2 = 9.234000147272726`;
A3 = -5.302489919999999`;
A4 = 1.1362478399999998`;
h0 = 45.5;
σM = 0.00592251
λ1 = 1.025;
λ2 = 1.308;

f1[y_, x_] = A1 + 2 A2 y[x] + 3 A3 y[x]^2 + 4 A4 y[x]^3
b[y_, x_] = h0^2/12 (5 A1 + 8 A2 y[x] + 9 A3 y[x]^2 + 8 A4 y[x]^3)/y[x]^6
g[y_, x_] = -(h0^2/12) (A1 + 2 A2 y[x] + 3 A3 y[x]^2 + 4 A4 y[x]^3)/y[x]^5

Sys = First@NDSolve[{
f1[y, x] + b[y, x] y'[x]^2 + g y''[x] == σM,
y[0] == λ1,
y[15] == λ2
}, y, {x, 0, 15}]
```

When I evaluate this code, Mathematica answers with the following errors:

> Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0.^6 encountered. >>
>   Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0. ComplexInfinity encountered. >>
>
> Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0.^6 encountered. >>
>
> Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0. ComplexInfinity encountered. >>
>
> Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0.^7 encountered. >>
>
> General::stop: Further output of Power::infy will be suppressed during this calculation. >>
>
> Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0. ComplexInfinity encountered. >>
>
> General::stop: Further output of Infinity::indet will be suppressed during this calculation. >>
>
> NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at x == 0.`. >>

As suggested [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolveBVP.html) (section: "StartingInitialConditions") I tried to wrote:

```
Sys = First@NDSolve[{
      f1[y, x] + b[y, x] y'[x]^2 + g y''[x] == σM,
      y[0] == λ1,
      y[15] == λ2}, y, {x, 0, 15}, 
      Method -> {"Shooting","StartingInitialConditions" -> {y[0] == λ1, y'[0] == 0.1}}]
```

followed by the following error:

> NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at x == 0.`. >>

How can I overtake this errors? What am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a `g` in your differential equation, I think you actually mean `g[y, x]`, right? This is the root of your problem. By the way, why do you make `y` an argument for functions `f1`, `b`, `g`? (It doesn't hurt though…) In fact, I think it will be conciser not to use function definitions in this case.

Then, your `"StartingInitialConditions"` for `Shooting` isn't so proper, I found a better one:

```
A0 = 2.0377638272727268`;
A1 = -7.105521894545453`;
A2 = 9.234000147272726`;
A3 = -5.302489919999999`;
A4 = 1.1362478399999998`;
h0 = 45.5;
σM = 0.00592251;
λ1 = 1.025;
λ2 = 1.308;

f1 = A1 + 2 A2 y[x] + 3 A3 y[x]^2 + 4 A4 y[x]^3;
b = h0^2/12 (5 A1 + 8 A2 y[x] + 9 A3 y[x]^2 + 8 A4 y[x]^3)/y[x]^6;
g = -(h0^2/12) (A1 + 2 A2 y[x] + 3 A3 y[x]^2 + 4 A4 y[x]^3)/y[x]^5;
eqn = f1 + b y'[x]^2 + g y''[x] - σM;

sol = NDSolve[{eqn == 0 , y[0] == λ1, y[15] == λ2}, y, {x, 0, 15}, 
               Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> 
                          {y[15] == λ2, y'[15] == 0}}]
Plot[y[x] /. sol, {x, 0, 15}]
Plot[eqn /. sol, {x, 0, 15}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

[image]

**Edit**

Some warnings will be generated when running the code above, but as shown in the second picture, the error of the solution is quite small, the only defect is, it doesn't match the left BC 囧. (Sorry I didn't notice it yesterday. ) But now I've got a really proper initial condition:

```
sol = NDSolve[{eqn == 0 , y[0] == λ1, y[15] == λ2}, y, {x, 0, 15}, 
               Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> 
                          {y[15] == λ2, y'[15] == 1/10 + 1/100 + 2/1000}}]
Plot[y[x] /. sol, {x, 0, 15}, PlotRange -> All, 
     Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Point[{{0, λ1}, {15, λ2}}]}]
Plot[eqn /. sol, {x, 0, 15}, PlotRange -> All]
(y[0] /. sol) - λ1
```

[image]

[image]

> {4.45117*10^-6}

I still found it by trial and error (with the help of `Table`).

Comment: Thanks very much: it works very well!!
But why does not it work if as starting point in the Shooting option I set y[0]==lambda1?

Comment: @Petrus I found the initial condition above by trial and error… I think it's part of the property of shooting method… sorry I can't give a deeper explain, but now I notice that maybe my answer can be better, I may improve it tomorrow.

Comment: @xzxzd thanks for your help

Comment: @Petrus See my edit.

Comment: xzczd:how the use of Table can help you?

Comment: @Petrus Just as a tool for method of exhaustion… Of course some observations for the plots of the solutions are also needed to narrow the range of exhaustion.

Answer (score 0):

Now I tried to change the interval as follows:

```
A0 = 2.0377638272727268`;
A1 = -7.105521894545453`;
A2 = 9.234000147272726`;
A3 = -5.302489919999999`;
A4 = 1.1362478399999998`;
h0 = 45.5;
σM = 0.00592251;
λ1 = 1.0253896074561006`;
λ2 = 1.3079437258774012`;

f1 = A1 + 2 A2 y[x] + 3 A3 y[x]^2 + 4 A4 y[x]^3;
b = h0^2/12 (5 A1 + 8 A2 y[x] + 9 A3 y[x]^2 + 8 A4 y[x]^3)/y[x]^6;
g = -(h0^2/12) (A1 + 2 A2 y[x] + 3 A3 y[x]^2 + 4 A4 y[x]^3)/y[x]^5;
eqn = f1 + b y'[x]^2 + g y''[x] - σM;

LA = 0;
LB = 15;

sol = NDSolve[{
     eqn == 0,
     y[LA] == λ1,
     y[LB] == λ2
     }, y, {x, 0, 15}, 
     Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> {y[LB] == λ2, y'[LB] == 0}}
     ]

Show[
     Plot[y[x] /. sol, {x, 0, LB}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {1, 1.32}}, Frame -> True],
     Graphics[{
     Red,
     Point[{{LA, λ1}, {LB, λ2}}]
      }]
    ]
```

If I set LB different from 15, something strange happens.. Moreover, even if LB = 15, the boundary condition in x = 0 is not satisfied. Where is the problem?

Comment: @I think it's better to add this to your question rather than post it as an answer… I recall a excellent answer by someone in this site to solve the problem here, but I'd like to go to bed now, you can look for it by yourself if you don't want to wait :), it's also a question about shooting method.

Comment: @xzczd: Now I'll look for this. How written [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24592/ode-with-boundary-value-problem-does-not-work), the real BC are

$$
\lambda (x\to - \infty) = \lambda_1 \qquad \lambda (x\to \infty) = \lambda_2
$$

I'm trying to have a larger domain for this reason

Comment: I found that question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18301/ndsolve-differential-equation-error , though it now appears that  it's not so applicable to your problem, I think you can still refer to it.

Comment: It's not surprising that the original initial condition becomes improper when the domain is changed, I guess the key point for solving your problem is to find a proper initial condition, which requires a lot of patience.

Comment: @xzczd: Now I'm studying my problem better in order to overtake my difficulties. Thanks for all :)