# Shooting method for solving 3rd Oder ODE with RK method

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear, boundary-condition-at-infinity

This is my 3rd Order IVP.
 `D[y[x], {x, 3}] ==  (m/2)*((D[y[x], x])^2 - 1) - ((m + 1)/2)*
   y*(D[y[x], {x, 2}])^2`. 
Initial conditions given are as follows `y[0] = 0;
y'[0] = 0;
y''[0] = 1; 
(* This is the First assumed value of y''[0] for
initializing shooting method using RK 4rth order method *)`

For this problem y'[infinity] is equal to 1, I want to loop the shooting method using
Runge Kutta 4 th order method in such a way that after calculations, 
it will check the y'[] value at sufficiently large value of x and from experimental results, for x ~ 7-8, f'[] is 1.

To Use RK method I redefined the equation like

```
D[l[x], {x, 2}] ==  z; D[y[x], x] ==  l; D[z[x], x] == (m/2)*(l^2 - 1) - ((m + 1)/2)*z*y;
```

Now I could write one loop for RK method but this is proving out a bit tough for me because I have to generate a list for different values of f[0] { 0,1} and m is also a variable with range (0-1) step size 0.01 & then I have to deal with 3 equations simultaneously.  I am solving this over C programming but its not that efficient. 
I dont know how to go ahead. If anyone could throw some light.....

Comment: Where's the definition of `m`? Then your equation involves simple mistake, `y*(D[y[x], {x, 2}])^2` should be `y[x] (D[y[x], {x, 2}])^2`. Finally, I tried to set `m = 1`, and this equation is easily solved by `NDSolve`.

Comment: Have there been some recent homework assignments on the shooting method? Seems to have been a few related questions recently. Is this a homework problem?

Comment: @xzczd- How could you solve this ODE with NDsolve. What you assumed the value of f''[0]. 
Since we only know f[0] and f'[0].
We do know f'[infinity]= 1 but we cant use this condition in NDSolve, that's why we have to use shooting method I guess. 
m is a list you can assume - {0.1,0.2,0.3...........1.0}.
f[0] is same list.
I wish to make a Module function which takes these euqation, perform RK method over them and solved and plot the results for different m and f[0].

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch- I dont know about any homework but this a problem related to Boundary layer flow with Wedge effect and Blowing and suction together.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch this also is applied as an approximation method in quantum chemistry. It converges slowly.

Comment: ** I used NDSolve but the results I am getting are totally wrong, dont know why** 

    s = NDSolve[{2*y'''[x] + ((1/3) + 1) y[x]*y''[x] + 
     2*(1/3)* (1 - (y'[x])^2) == 
    0, \[Theta]''[x] + 0.5*0.72*(1/3 + 1)*y[x]*\[Theta]'[x] == 0, 
   y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0, 
   y'[6.6] == 1, \[Theta][0] == 0, \[Theta][6.4] == 1}, {y, y', 
   y'', \[Theta]}, {x, 0, 20}]

Comment: **Using NDSolve for this problem is giving  incorrect answers**
**Reason might be that since f'[infinity]=1 but I cant use this in my NDSolve argument**
**The function increases rapidly and f'[0] is practically one at x ~ 6.6**
**If I use this condition, the values I am getting are negative means if f[2]= x then what I am getting is f[2]= -x**.
**Thats why I said we need to use shooting technique**

Comment: `s = NDSolve[{2*y'''[x] + ((1/3) + 1) y[x]*y''[x] + 
     2*(1/3)* (1 - (y'[x])^2) == 
    0, \[Theta]''[x] + 0.5*0.72*(1/3 + 1)*y[x]*\[Theta]'[x] == 0, 
   y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0, 
   y'[7] == 1, \[Theta][0] == 0, \[Theta][6.4] == 1}, {y, y', 
   y'', \[Theta]}, {x, 0, 20}]`

`Plot[Evaluate[{y[x], y'[x], y''[x], \[Theta][x]} /. s], {x, 0, 5}]`

Comment: Seems that since you add a `-` after my name, I didn't receive the message for your comment. I chose the initial condition `y''[0] == 1` for I didn't notice it's just assumed and the actually boundary is `f'[Infinity] == 1`, then, if you want to apply shooting method, you may be interested in [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/24660/1871) and [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28713/1871).